# .HttpContext.User is null after successful login from SAML Identity Provider?

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

Trying to retrofit an old webforms application.

Got my configuration working so that it's prompting for login and successfully redirecting back to the application.  The folks that manage the IP can see the response is generated.

However in the callback to my application the User is null.  I'm told if it's configured correctly it should be populated.

We have a custom IHttpModule and that is where I can see getting hit with the call to /Saml2/Acs with the User not populated.  I think this may be expected as the handler for that is supposed to populate the  User, I think?  However the following call (the returnUrl configured in sustainsys.Saml2) still has no User and I don't see any sort of error or anything.

Anyone with experience have an idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue turned out to be that I had another authentication module loaded before SessionAuthenticationModule and Saml2AuthenticationModule in the web config.

The comment in the  example was

```
 Add these modules below any existing. The SessionAuthenticatioModule
            must be loaded before the Saml2AuthenticationModule
```

However in my case with I had another authentication module involved that needed to go last.

Answer (score 1):

The call to /Saml2/Acs should be taken care of by the `Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule`. It will process the response and then call the `SessionAuthenticationModule` to set a cookie that preservers the `User` across calls.

To get some more information about what's happening in the library, you can assign an implementation of `ILoggerAdapter` to `Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.Options.FromConfiguration.SPOPtions.Logger` to get some logging output from the library.